# Spring JPA - Is there a good way for inner join between entities or the only way is JPQL?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following Entities:

```
@Entity
public class Organisation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    // ...
}

@Entity
public class Section{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    // ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "organisation_id", nullable = false)
    private Organisation organisation;
}

@Entity
public class SubSection {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    // ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "section_id")
    private Section section;
}
```

Now I want to find all `SubSections` by `Organisation` `Id`. Right now I am doing it using `JPQL` at the `SubSectionRepository` as above:

```
public interface SubSectionRepository extends JpaRepository<SubSection, Long>{

@Query(value = "SELECT ss.* FROM sub_section as ss INNER JOIN section as s ON ss.section_id = s.id WHERE s.organisation_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<SubSection> findByOrganisation(Long organisationId);
    
}
```

Is there any way that I can make `INNER JOIN` using the JpaRepository interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this way

```
subsectionRepository.findBySectionOrganizationId(long organizationId)
```

Comment: Yeap this is it. I have not tried it. It works perfectly. Thank you for your answer. I would like to ask for any related documentation?

Answer (score 2):

- Update your method to

```
public interface SubSectionRepository extends JpaRepository<SubSection, Long>  {

    List<SubSection> findBySectionOrganisationId(Long organisationId);
}
```

- Hibernate **will** generate something like this.

```
    select subsec.*,
    from sub_section subsec 
    left outer join section sec on subsection.section_id=sec.id 
    left outer join organisation org on section.organisation_id=org.id 
    where org.id=?
```

- Don't worry about the `left join` term. It is actually a `inner join` because you have a `where` condition with `id =` on the most right table. Because of that, it effectively becomes a `inner join`. I.e if there is no record on the right table for that record, it will be ignored.